# Словарь из кортежа кортежей в Python

Tags: python, типы-данных

Есть кортеж вида:

```
(("key1", "val1"), ("key2", "val2"), ("key3", "val3"))
```

Как из него сделать словарь?

```
{
  'key1': 'val1', 
  'key2': 'val2', 
  'key3': 'val3'
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
dict(кортеж)
```